# Error deploying SSRS report to Dynamics AX 2009

Tags: ssrs-2008, dynamics-ax-2009

I have a very simple Dynamics AX Reporting project with a dataset using the Dynamics AX data source hitting a custom query I created in the AOT.  The report builds succesfully in VS2008, and when I attempt to deploy the report, an error is returned "**Deployment failed unexpectedly with the message: The following components have not been installed or are not configured correctly: Reporting Extensions**".  The "Save to AOD" function also returns an "unknown error."

The VS2008 error shows the problem to be on the line referencing the DeployToReportsServerTask in the file:
Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.Design.Reporting.Modeling.targets

[image: Code snippet of line 374 where error is occuring]

From within AX, using the Reporting servers form (Administration > Setup > Business analysis > Reporting Services > Reporting Servers), the Validate (button) returns a "success" message. Also, I can browse the reports directory on the server and my local PC through IE.  My AX client configuration also launches & connects to the correct AOS.

Any ideas as to what may be the problem?  Not sure what else I can check.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was reporting tools also had to be installed on the AOS server (with the reporting extensions).  The reporting tools were only installed on my dev box.  Additionally, my deployment process was also not correct.  The correct process in my environment is:

1) In VS (on dev box), on the reports library project node in the solution explorer, right click, Save to AOD
2) In AX (on AOS), open report libraries in AOT, find library, right click, deploy (follow prompts).
3) open in IE and run reports.

Answer (score 0):

Is this helpful?

> Then login to aos server. Open internet explorer. browse the report server and manager url. If you can
>   see the dynamics ax folder just try to get inside the folder and browse a single report manually. If you
>   may able to browse then there is no issue eixt. Just restart the iis on reporting server. If you may not
>   able to browse then add the particular port to firewall. or disable the firewall. In the mean time just chekc
>   you may using NTLM authentication or kerberos authentication.

From:
http://daynamicsaxaptatutorials.blogspot.no/2012/03/reports-get-build-up-secussfully-bot.html

Comment: Thank you Skaue for the link!  The only thing that is different in my environment than what the post suggests is that my folder name is "Dynamics" instead of "Dynamics AX".  Otherwise, I can browse to the reports with no issues.  I also read in the AX 2009 installation guide that "Reporting Services 2008 does not require IIS".

Comment: I didn't specify in my original post that we are using AX2009 on a server that runs Windows Server 2003 with SQL 2008 with Kerberos authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Dynamics AX Configuration utility, is the Target "Business connector (non-interactive use only)" set up to point to the correct AOS?

Comment: Good thought!  My business connector was NOT configured to point to the correct AOS, but after fixing it, I'm still getting the same exact error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but I resolved this by using VS in Administrative Mode i.e. Open the VS as Administrator.

Don't know how but it will help me.

HTH

Sachin